# Weights occurring in a multiple of a dominant weight

Tags: combinatorics, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a simple Lie algebra and let $V(\lambda)$ be a finite dimensional irreducible representation with highest weight $\lambda$. Suppose I know all the weights occurring in $V(\lambda)$. Is there a way to write down all the weights occurring in $V(2\lambda)$ in terms of the weights of $V(\lambda)$ ?